# p:fileupload image preview is not working

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, jsf-2

I am using prime faces file upload feature in my application form, whenever i upload the file it is not displaying the preview image in screen.

I would like to know which attribute and class to refer for this issue. please find the sample code below.

```
<fileUpload
    id="uploadImage"
    fileLimit="1" 
    fileUploadListener="#{publicSarFormDataBean.handleFileUpload}"
    process="@form"
    mode="advanced"
    multiple="false"
    auto="true"  
    onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()"
    oncomplete="PF('statusDialog').hide(), PF('documentListTbl').filter()"
    dragDropSupport="true"
    sizeLimit="1000000000" 
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(png|jpeg|JPEG|jpg|JPG)$/"
    invalidFileMessage="File is invalid"
    update="messages"
    styleClass="Fleft FontBold">
</p:fileUpload>
```

Comment: please put more code, you want to show the image in datatable??

Comment: Normal form .It contains text field and submit button

Comment: you want to see an example with croping?

Comment: put you p:graphicImage code...

Comment: Even better, create a [mcve]

Comment: fileupload having mode advance option but it is not working for me.  Just coming and disappearing in the page.

Answer (score 2):

The 'preview' is only relevant **before** uploading. And since you have `auto="true"` the files are automatically uploaded and a preview in the `p:fileUpload` is useless.

It is all working fine in the [PrimeFaces upload showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/dnd.xhtml)